# Cross compile QtModules for raspberry pi 3

Tags: c++, qt, module, raspberry-pi3

I need to cross compile QSerialPort module and QtChart Module for the pi cm3 on Ubuntu x64, after having successfully compiled qtbase following the https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step guide.

In the same guide is told to compile other modules in the following way:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/<qt-module>.git -b <qt-version>
cd <qt-module>

~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake -r
make
make install
```

I tried that method with

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git
cd qtserialPort
```

but doing

```
~/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake -r
```

i get the error

```
Project MESSAGE: cmake executable not found. Not running CMake unit tests
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [this file](https://github.com/qt/qtserialport/blob/5.10/tests/auto/cmake/cmake.pro) in the QtSerialPort repository, it seems like there is some kind of integration with CMake's CTest framework. Hence, to get rid of the message, I guess you could try to install CMake:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

However, I am not sure if this actually is an error (as it says `Project MESSAGE` - it might just be informational and safe to ignore).